# Questions Voting System with [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a system that people can vote or answer some question saved in the data base. Basically the questions could have two or several answers (and answers could be choosing by checkboxes or radio-buttons depending of the type of questions)

My models are like following:

Questions model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:answer].blank? } 
end
```

Answers Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :votes
end
```

Users model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :votes
end
```

Votes model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :answer
end
```

This is more or less the form I want to do, it shows the question first then the answers with the option to chose, checkbox or radio buttons, then a submit button to save the vote
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3zdr.png or see below
[image]

Any suggestions how to build the form would be really thankful !!!

Routes:

```
$ rake routes
            votes GET    /votes(.:format)                                   votes#index
                  POST   /votes(.:format)                                   votes#create
         new_vote GET    /votes/new(.:format)                               votes#new
        edit_vote GET    /votes/:id/edit(.:format)                          votes#edit
             vote GET    /votes/:id(.:format)                               votes#show
                  PATCH  /votes/:id(.:format)                               votes#update
                  PUT    /votes/:id(.:format)                               votes#update
                  DELETE /votes/:id(.:format)                               votes#destroy
```

Comment: Where does "voting" come into this? Are the answers "votes" basically?

Comment: votes are answers as well as the user who votes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do 
    resources :votes, only: [:new, :create], as: "vote", path: "vote" #-> /questions/1/vote
end

#app/controllers/votes.rb
def new
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @vote = Vote.new
end

def create
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)
    @vote.save
end

private

def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:answer_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end

#app/views/votes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @vote do |f| %>
    <%= @question.title %>

    Answers:
    <% @question.answer.each do |answer| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %> #-> need to check syntax
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Go" %>

<% end %>
```

This will submit a vote with the corresponding `answer_id` and `user_id`. Although I feel it should have `question_id` too

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the tip what about if it consists to checkboxes to chose many answer, should I pass a set of answer_ids to the controller then save many votes or should I do it in different tables? By the way when I try to enter to the vote page by         <%= button_to 'Vote', new_vote_path(question_id: question) %>b it says No route matches [POST] "/votes/new".. shouldn't be GET?

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for the comment! You have to remember I had precious little to work with for this :)

Comment: The way I saw it was that you're creating a vote from a series of answers. You'd set the potential answers for the question in the backend of the app somewhere, meaning when you go on this page, you're really just making a new vote (considering answers & questions are already created)

Comment: It should be `POST` - can you give us a dump of your `rake routes`?

Comment: Hi Rich, yes exactly the vote are from a series of answers already created. My question is if I am using checkboxes I will have more than one answer selected, my question is how can I take these answers to the controller and save them.

Comment: I attach my routes above,